# How to be connected to a private network through WIFI, but not connected to the internet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet

I have a WIFI router that provides me with wireless internet. Several computers and devices in my home are connected to the internet through this device.

Now, let's say I have a computer with Win 10, which provides my home network with a specific service. Obviously, it should be connected to the WIFI.

However, because of some reason, it would be ideal for me to have this specific machine completely off the internet. No inbound and no outbound traffic whatsoever. Completely off through the whole machine, and not just, for example, the browser. Is this possible to have this device connected to the private network, but disconnected from the public (Internet) network?

Comment: Yes. Manually give it a static IP address on your LAN, but don't give it a default gateway (don't let it get a normal config via DHCP). Disable IPv6 just in case so it can't autoconfigure based on router advertisements.

Comment: @Spiff Thank you, but id didn't work. It cut me off of both public and private networks.

Comment: Check your router if it has an option to block external access to a specific machine. If you share your router model here, somebody familiar with the specific model may be able to help with the settings (for example in my Asus router I can go to the client list, click on the specific client and I get an option "Block Internet Access"). Many routers have similar settings.

Comment: @gepa that was actually very smart! Thank you. My router is a Huawei WA8021V5.